# Rake task to download and unzip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, unzip

I would like to update a *cities* table every week to reflect changes in cities across the world. I am creating a Rake task for the purpose. **If possible, I would like to do this without adding another gem dependency**.

The zipped file is a publicly available zipped file at [geonames.org/15000cities.zip](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/cities15000.zip).

My attempt:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'zip'

namespace :geocities do
  desc "Rake task to fetch Geocities city list every 3 days"
  task :fetch do

    uri = URI('http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/cities15000.zip')
    zipped_folder = Net::HTTP.get(uri) 

    Zip::File.open(zipped_folder) do |unzipped_folder| #erroring here
      unzipped_folder.each do |file|
        Rails.root.join("", "list_of_cities.txt").write(file)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The return from `rake geocities:fetch`

```
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: string contains null byte
```

As detailed, I'm trying to unzip the file and save it to a *list_of_cities.txt* file. Once I the methodology down for accomplishing this, I believe I can figure out how to update my db, based on the file. (But if you have opinions on how best to handle the actual db update, other than my planned way, I'd love to hear them. But that seems like a different post entirely.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will save `zipped_folder` to disk, then unzip it and save its contents:

```ruby
require 'net/http'                                                              
require 'zip'                                                                   

namespace :geocities do                                                         
  desc "Rake task to fetch Geocities city list every 3 days"                    
  task :fetch do                                                                

    uri = URI('http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/cities15000.zip')                          
    zipped_folder = Net::HTTP.get(uri)                                          

    File.open('cities.zip', 'wb') do |file|                                      
      file.write(zipped_folder)                                                 
    end                                                                         

    zip_file = Zip::File.open('cities.zip')                                     
    zip_file.each do |file|                                                     
      file.extract
    end                                                                         
  end                                                                           
end
```

This will extract all files inside the zip file, in this case `cities15000.txt`.
You can  then read the contents of `cities15000.txt` and update your database.

If you want to extract to a different file name, you can pass it to `file.extract` like this:

```ruby
zip_file.each do |file|                                                     
    file.extract('list_of_cities.txt')
end
```

Comment: `rake aborted! Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\x9C" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8` - occurring at the File.open block.
I believe this is because we're trying to write a compressed folder to a file?

Comment: The compressed folder is a zipped file. So it is OK to write it to a file. I tried it myself and it worked fine.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something. I tried just copying and pasting your code in with no luck (with output error noted above). Do I need to alter any of it? I'll gladly _accept_ this answer.

Comment: All we need to do to clean this up is use a binary File.open mode!

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be done more easily without ruby, just using `wget` and `unzip`:

```
namespace :geocities do
  desc "Rake task to fetch Geocities city list every 3 days"
  task :fetch do
     `wget -c --tries=10 http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/cities15000.zip | unzip`
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a viable option. But I'm trying to avoid using wget, as implementing a command line approach is less robust and debug-friendly, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution of downloading a zip from a remote URL to the local and unzipping to the tmp file location.

```
url = 'https://example.com/path/to/your_zip_file.zip'

destination = Rails.root.join('tmp', 'your_zip_file.zip')

system("curl -L -o '#{destination}' '#{url}'")


# Unzip the downloaded file using a system command
system("unzip '#{destination}' -d '#{Rails.root.join('tmp')}'")
```